# How to Buffering one video in background while playing one?

Tags: android, video, media-player

I have one activity where i got two video URL.So, once the activity started i have set one progress dialog which spins till the first video is prepared.So once first video started , i want to buffer the second video in background(First Video is still playing in foreground).Right now i am showing one progress dialog till the video prepared.So once the first video is finished ,i want to immediately start the second one.So user feels like that its an one video.

Any help will be appreciated....

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: I'm also trying this with 2 Video Views(one visible in the foreground, one invisible in the background) but I'm using streamed videos (HLS) and it seems like the videos won't buffer unless play() is called...did you manage to sort this?

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing, the only difference is that I don't need it in VideoView since I'm using custom player (textureview and mediaplayer). Did you find any solution?